# Sum the values in excel with matching and changing criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, sumifs

Referring to the linked picture below. Is there a way to sum values in "size" depending on two criteria: 1. the "label" is the same as "class", 2. when the "label" changes (i.e. at row 3,8,...) it stops searching for criteria 1.

For example,

```
D2 = A2+A3
D3 = A4+A5+A6+A7+A8
D4 = A9+A10
D5 = A11+A12+A13+A14
D6 = A15+A16
D7 = A17+A18+A19+A20+A21.
```

The code I used was =sumifs(A:A,B:B,C2); however this formula does not give what I want and it outputs D2 = A2+A3+A9+A10+A17+A18+A19+A20+A21.

[image]

Comment: Without clicking on your link, you can try using SUMIFS().

Comment: Here is something to consider in `D2` try the following array entered formula: `=SUM(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(B$2:B$21<>B$1:B$20,ROW(B$2:B$21),""),ROW(A1))):INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(B$2:B$21<>B$3:B$22,ROW(B$2:B$21),""),ROW(A1))))`. Now this is a way to retrieve areas within the A column and you could start using this if you still need to check against column C.